# What's the probability that there's at least one ball in every bin if 2n balls are placed into n bins?

Tags: probability

I've been working on this all day long. Here's what I've done until now.The denominator is easy. It's $n^{2n}$. I compute the numerator as follows.

All $n$ bins have at least one ball = $n$ bins must have one of the $2n$ balls each + the remaining $n$ balls are placed in any of the bins in any fashion.

Now I solve the first part. $n$ balls can be chosen out of $2n$ balls in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways, and they can be placed in $n!$ ways in the $n$ bins. Hence multiplying them yields $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)$.

I have no clue how to proceed with the second part. Please help. Also please correct if I am wrong in the way I've proceeded so far.

Comment: But I guess I've done something wrong in my first step too. Because for n=2, this does not yield the correct result. Any hint would be of great help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach that you started on is a good one. The "total" count was right, but the count of the "favourable" cases was not. Let us generalize slightly. We throw $m$ (numbered) balls, one at a time, at a line of $x$ (numbered) buckets, and ask for the probability that none of the buckets ends up empty.

There are $x^m$ outcomes, all *equally likely*. We now need to count the number of outcomes for which none of the buckets is empty.  There is unfortunately *no known closed form* for this number.

However, the number of ways of dividing a set of $m$ elements into $x$ non-empty subsets has a *name*.  It is the *Stirling number of the second kind*. One common notation is $S(m,x)$. Another looks like a binomial coefficient symbol, with $\{\}$ instead of $()$.

So (by definition) we can divide our set of $m$ objects into $x$ non-empty subsets in $S(m,x)$ ways. For every such division, we can assign these subsets to the buckets, one subset to each bucket, in $x!$ ways. This gives us a total of $x!S(m,x)$ ways, and our probability is therefore
$$\frac{x!S(m,x)}{x^m}.$$
For your particular problem, let $m=2n$ and $x=n$.

There is no known closed form for $S(m,x)$.  Perhaps there is a closed form for the special case $S(2n,n)$ that you need. I do not see one immediately, but have not thought enough about it.

There are nice *recurrences* for the Stirling numbers of the second kind.  We can also get pleasant expressions for them as *sums*, by using the principle of inclusion/exclusion.  To give you a beginning on that, we start counting the number of ways to have no bucket empty.

There are $x^m$ ways to distribute the balls.  How many have bucket $i$ empty? Clearly $(x-1)^m$. Which bucket will be empty can be chosen in $\binom{x}{1}$ ways. So as a first step to our count, we arrive at $x^m-\binom{x}{1}(x-1)^m$.

However, we have subtracted too much, since the cases where $i$ is empty and $j$ is empty have been subtracted twice from $x^m$.  So for every (unordered) pair $i$, $j$, we must add back the $(x-2)^m$ assignments in which buckets $i$ and $j$ are empty. This gives us the new estimate $x^m-\binom{x}{1}(x-1)^m+\binom{x}{2}(x-2)^m$.

However, we have added back one too many times all the cases where $3$ of the buckets are empty. Continue.  We end up with an attractive sum, that has no known closed form, and that is of course a close relative of $S(m,x)$.

**Remark:** Unfortunately, for the probability model in which each ball is equally likely to end up in any bucket, with independence between balls, a "Stars and Bars" approach won't work. Yes, we can get a count of the number of ways to distribute $m$ identical balls between $x$ buckets. We can also get a count of the number of ways to distribute so that no bucket is empty. But then we run into a **fatal** complication.  The different ways to distribute $m$ identical balls among $x$ buckets are **not** equally likely.

Comment: Awesome answer! I have posted a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382115/probability-that-at-least-k-cards-will-go-into-a-bucket but we couldn't be able to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) as a tool for dealing with these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Never heard of that before. Will look into it.